# Compare rows which belongs to different ids group under another id and print a result in a separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm looking for a SQL query solution that would allow me to compare different attributes and their values, which are in rows, for different ids which are grouped under a parent id. I would like to print the result on whether it's a match or not in a separate column. The screenshot below which contains data and the desired result marked in red.

[image: Check out this use case]

Adding here the results I got while running the query from GMB. I also added a column Excpected_Result so that we can easily see the differences:
[GMB query vs expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73lLV.png)

Comment: I'm trying currently solve the issue with CASE WHEN statement, but it seems it doesn't work as expected for now

Comment: Feel free to provide your attempts so that we can point out possible improvements or an explanation as to why your query is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and a conditional expression:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by attributeName, attributeValue) > 1 
        then 'True'
        else 'False'
    end has_match
from mytable t
```

Comment: Hi. Still doesn't work as expected. I've added above a screenshot so that we can see the differences between Expected_Result and has_match columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not too big, you can join it to itself on GroupNumber and AttributeName like that:

```
SELECT 

t1.AttributeName, t1.AttributeValue, t2.AttributeValue, CASE WHEN t1.AttributeValue = t2.AttributeValue THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as Result

FROM Table AS t1
     INNER JOIN Table AS t2 ON t1.GroupNumber = t2.GroupNumber AND t1.AttributeName = t2.AttributeName
```

Comment: Thank you, Artur, for quick reaction. It doesn't work the way I expect, but maybe I wasn't too clear on what I try to achieve - I need to compare AttributeValue from one set of id against another id which resides in the same task/parent id you can say. E.g. NAME from ID:888 should be compared with NAME from ID:777 if match then print for both TRUE